# Combining array entries by the first value

Tags: python, multidimensional-array

so I have an array of the form...

```
[[1,454,435][1,332,646][2,342,765][3,234,343][3,565,965]...]
```

(there are a couple of hundred of sublists)

and I want to turn it into an array of the following form:

```
[[1,454,435,332,646][2,342,765],[3,234,343,565,965]...]
```

I've considered doing a nested loop to iterate over the sublists then the values but I'm just not really sure how to create the new array or combine the ones I have.

Comment: Please provide the code you have worked on so far.

Comment: What language are you working in? Which is it, Python or D?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

try this

```
data = [[1,454,435],[1,332,646],[2,342,765],[3,234,343],[3,565,965]]
result = []
temp = []
for x in data:
    if x[0] not in temp:
        temp.append(x[0])
        result.append(x)
    else:
        for y in range(1,len(x)):
            result[temp.index(x[0])].append(x[y])


print(result)
```

Comment: I don't think that's the solution he is looking for. He wants to be able to convert his original list to look like your ```data``` variable.

Comment: @roshshetty I don't understand your comment. The output of this code is what the OP wants their data to look like, so in that sense it is correct. However, I think it is a bad answer regardless because of the *O(n^2)* complexity (outer `for` x `not in`).

Answer (score 0):

D solution:

```
a
.chunkBy!((a, b) => a[0] == b[0])
.map!(subgroup => chain(
    subgroup.front[0].only,
    subgroup.map!(subgroup => subgroup[1 .. $]).joiner
))
```

https://run.dlang.io/is/n995bb